# Не работают ссылки в c++. Пожалуйста, помогите или исправьте!

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки

Я пытался изменять переменные из функции `main()` сначала с помощью указателей, а потом с помощью ссылок, как было указано в одной из статей на этом сайте, но ничего не помогло.

```
int main()
{
    int bl_br_coun = 0, coun_lay = 10;
    bool pick = false, las = false, bomb = false;//!Апгрейды персонажа
    bool level_complete = false;
    bool floor_game = true, wall_game_r = true, wall_game_l = true;
    int curt_lev = 0;
    float acs = 0.2, vel_x = 2, vel_y = 0;
    float height = 60, length = 40;
    float bl_range = 60;
    float x_hero = 0, y_hero = 0;
    int Points = 0;
    txCreateWindow(1138, 640);
    level_campaing_1(bl_range, x_hero, y_hero, x_hero, y_hero, vel_x,
                     vel_y, vel_y, acs, height, length);
    return 0;
}


void level_campaing_1(float bl_range, float& x_hero_adr,
                      float& y_hero_adr, float x_hero, float y_hero, float vel_x,
                      float vel_y, float& vel_y_adr, float acs, float height, float length)
{
    startpos_camp_1(x_hero_adr, y_hero_adr);
    curt_lev = 1;

    while (endingcamp[0] == false)
    {
        while (floor_game == true)
        {
            level_blocks_camp_1(bl_range);
            game(bl_range, x_hero_adr, y_hero_adr, x_hero, y_hero, vel_x, vel_y,
                 height, length);
            Pickaxe(x_hero, y_hero, height, length);
            update();
        }

        while (floor_game == false)
        {
            level_blocks_camp_1(bl_range);
            game(bl_range, x_hero_adr, y_hero_adr, x_hero, y_hero, vel_x, vel_y,
                 height, length);
            fall(vel_y_adr, acs);
            update();
        }

        vel_y_adr = 0;
    }
}
void game(float bl_range, float& x_hero_adr, float& y_hero_adr, float
          x_hero, float y_hero, float vel_x, float vel_y, float height,
          float length)
{
    hero_movement(x_hero_adr, y_hero_adr, vel_x, vel_y);
    floor_wall_ch(bl_range, x_hero, y_hero, length, height);
    Heroanim_1(x_hero, y_hero, height, length);
}
void hero_movement(float& x_hero, float& y_hero, float vel_x,
                   float vel_y)
{
    y_hero += vel_y;

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
    {
        if (wall_game_r == false)
        {
            x_hero += vel_x;
        }
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
    {
        if (wall_game_l == false)
        {
            x_hero -= vel_x;
        }
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
    {
        if (vel_y = 0)
        {
            vel_y = -4;
        }
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
    {
    }
}
void startpos_camp_1(float& x_hero, float& y_hero)
{
    x_hero = 260;
    y_hero = 400;
}
```

Функции startpos_camp_1 и hero_movement должны изменять переменные `x_hero` и `y_hero`, но по факту они не меняются. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: Покажите, где вы их используете (вызываете эти функции) - потому что чудес не бывает...

Comment: я вызываю их прямиком в main через другую функцию

Comment: void game (float bl_range, float &x_hero_adr, float &y_hero_adr, float x_hero, float y_hero, float vel_x, float vel_y, float height, float length)
{
    hero_movement (x_hero_adr, y_hero_adr, vel_x, vel_y);
    floor_wall_ch (bl_range, x_hero, y_hero, length, height);
    Heroanim_1 (x_hero, y_hero, height, length);
}

Comment: Покажите код. И вообще - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Все я добавил все нужные части кода

Comment: https://ideone.com/ENviw7 - пришлось ваш код обрезать. Как видите, **уже после первой строки** значения меняются. Как вы определили, что они не меняются? в `main` вы их не проверяете...

Comment: я запустил код и функция которая рисует персонажа по его координатам, рисует его в точке (0;0), а не в указанной.

Comment: Ну так а что вы ей передаете? (См. PS к моему ответу). У вас код такой, что вы в нем сами путаетесь (т.н. "спагетти-код")...

Comment: я передаю ей x_hero, y_hero

Comment: А МЕНЯЕТЕ `x_hero_adr`!!! Что вы после этого хотите?

Answer (score 0):

Если это ваш код -

```
void game(float bl_range, float& x_hero_adr, float& y_hero_adr,
          float x_hero, float y_hero, float vel_x, float vel_y, float height,
          float length)
{
    hero_movement(x_hero_adr, y_hero_adr, vel_x, vel_y);
    floor_wall_ch(bl_range, x_hero, y_hero, length, height);
    Heroanim_1(x_hero, y_hero, height, length);
}
```

и `game()` вызывается в `main`, то, поскольку в `game()` вы передаете `x_hero` и `y_hero` по значению, а не по ссылке, то изменения в самой `main` не происходит. Впрочем, у вас такая каша с именованием переменных, что понять, что же именно передается - проблематично. Одна `x_hero_adr`, передаваемая по ссылке, а затем передаваемая в качестве параметра `x_hero` в другую функцию, чего стоит. Я бы порекомендовал несколько причесать ваш код - все же 9 параметров функции - это многовато...

Если нет - то приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

P.S. Но, по-моему, вы просто запутались в своих переменных.

Меняете координаты в `x_hero_adr`, `y_hero_adr`

```
hero_movement (x_hero_adr, y_hero_adr, vel_x, vel_y);
```

И забываете про них, используя `x_hero`, `y_hero`:

```
floor_wall_ch (bl_range, x_hero, y_hero, length, height);
Heroanim_1 (x_hero, y_hero, height, length);
```

Что-то меня терзают смутные сомнения, что это не то, что вы хотели сделать :)

Кстати, у вас C++ - так почему бы не воспользоваться классами?...

Comment: я еще учусь c++ и не знаю что такое классы :)

Comment: Простите, конечно, но тогда имеет смысл потренироваться на чем-то попроще? Игры сами по себе сложная область, так зачем же еще и усложнять себе задачу?

Comment: ну классы мы пока не изучали, просто сказали мол переведите все в указатели с глобальных переменных и все ну и получилось что получилось.

Comment: Это же обязательный проект по этому отказаться я от него не могу.

Comment: Но все равно спасибо вам огромное за помощь.

Comment: 8-0 (Смайлика с достаточной степенью удивления не придумал) Ну хоть структуры из C вы можете использовать? Просто таскать из функции в функцию такое количество параметров - очень запутывает. Откровенно говоря, тогда уж лучше - несмотря на все рекомендации - плюнуть и использовать глобальные переменные...